# Paragraph breaks irregularly

Tags: php, dompdf

I have some text with paragraph number formatted as follows

```
<p><span class="par_no">1</span> Here follows the paragraph text</p>
<p><span class="par_no">3</span> Here follows the paragraph text</p>
...
```

I'm having some problems using dompdf because on some page breaks the paragraph is breaked, with the paragraph number (`<span class="par_no">1</span>`) on the first page and the rest of the text in the next new page.
I tried to control the output using css:

```
span.par_no{
  page-break-after: avoid;
}
```

but it did not help.

The same issue happens sometimes when the last line of a page contains formating, `<i></i>`, `<em></em>`, `<stong></strong>` or `<b></b>` tags. The line is interrupted just after the tag, despite the fact the end of the line is not reached, and a new line in a new page is started.

Comment: I don't know what to answer, because I don't understand the question. It seems to a matter contacting the developer/support of dompdf?

Comment: Which version of dompdf? In trying to suss out the issue I did rediscover a bug around [paging text contained within an inline block](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/565). It could be related to your issue, but it's hard to say without more information. Can you post a HTML/CSS document exhibiting the problem?

Comment: Hello, I'm using dompdf v. 0.6.0 beta 3. I'll prepare a zip package with the html, css and the pdf. Thank you.

Comment: @BrianS I think the bug reported in GitHub you linked here is the same I'm experiencing. I think there is no need to post my code. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's just a mistake asking your question or the real problem, but the class is not the same in the html and the css. You have "no_par" and "par_no".